# Unable to sync OneNote with password on section on WP8

Tags: sync, password, onenote

I have recently added a password to some, but not all of my sections in a OneNote notebook on my PC. Now that I have done that, I have an issue trying to sync sections on my Windows Phone 8 through the OneNote application. I am getting the following message:

> Onenote can't open or sync this file because it is password protected. Error code = e000032a

I found this [post](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/winphone/forum/wp7-sync/opening-a-password-protected-section-of-onenote-on/8173cd95-a681-4b15-a3fc-7f4be43c7e69), which mentions this functionality is not supported yet...Can anyone clarify this or does anyone have any further information on this issue?

Comment: also found this [reference](https://twitter.com/nickwest_wyy/status/291670511749038080).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's correct, the functionality is only supported in OneNote which comes with Office. The Windows Phone 8, Windows 8 (Metro) and SkyDrive online apps unfortunately don't support this feature.